# c - How can I make this program's win statements recursive?

Tags: c, recursion

Here is the program:

```
/*MAIN*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ticTacToe.h"


int main(void) {
  boardSet(); // sets the board up
  playGame(); // starts the game
}





/*ticTacToe.c*/
//add diagonal check
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ticTacToe.h"

int x = 0;
void boardSet(){
  for(n=0;n<3;n++){ //  sets row 0 to x
    board[0][n] = '#';
  }
  for(n=0;n<3;n++){ //  sets row 1 to x
    board[1][n] = '#';
  }
  for(n=0;n<3;n++){ //  sets row 2 to x
    board[2][n] = '#';
  }
}

void playGame(){ //starts the game, include both players turns and then repeats
  playerOne();
  playerTwo();
  playGame();
}

void display(){
  printf("\n");//formatting
  for(n=0;n<3;n++) // for statement to print row 0
    printf("%c\t",board[0][n]);  
  printf("\n");//formatting
  for(n=0;n<3;n++) //for statement to print row 1
    printf("%c\t",board[1][n]);  
  printf("\n");//formatting
  for(n=0;n<3;n++)//for statement to print row 2
    printf("%c\t",board[2][n]);
  printf("\n");//formatting
}

void playerOne(){
  x = 0;
  //ask for and gets playerOne's input
  char input[BUFFER] = {0};
  printf("Player one:");
  fgets(input, BUFFER, stdin);

  //if there's an open space put an o there
  if(board[input[0]-97][input[1]-49] == '#'){
    board[input[0]-97][input[1]-49] = 'o';
    display(); //shows the board
    }

  //if there's no an open space try again
  else if((board[input[0]-97][input[1]-49] != '#')){
    printf("Please select an open spot\n");
    playerOne();
  }


  checkWin(); //checks to see if, after that move, one of the players win
}

void playerTwo(){
  x = 0;
  //asks for and gets playerTwo's input
  char input[BUFFER] = {0};
  printf("Player two:");
  fgets(input, BUFFER, stdin);

  //if there's an open space put an x there
  if(board[input[0]-97][input[1]-49] == '#'){
    board[input[0]-97][input[1]-49] = 'x';
    display();
  }

  //if there's not an open space try again
  else if((board[input[0]-97][input[1]-49] != '#')){
    printf("Please select an open spot\n");
    playerTwo();
  }

  //display(); //shows the board
  checkWin(); //checks to see if, after that move, one of the players win
}

void checkWin(){ // checks if one of the players win, checks rows, then the columns and then the diagonals
  int continueGame = 0;
  rowCheck();
  x=0;
  columnCheck();
  diagonalCheck();
  for(x=0;x<=2;x++){ // if all of the spaces have been taken up, call a draw
    if(board[x][COUNT] == '#' || board[x][COUNT+1] == '#' || board[x][COUNT+2] == '#')
      continueGame = 1;
  }
  if (continueGame == 0){
    printf("Draw!");
    exit(1);
    }

}

void rowCheck(){ //checks rows, repeats going down the rows
  //printf("x: %d\n",x); //for debugging
  //row check, if row 1 is all o's, then player one wins and the program ends
  if(board[x][COUNT] == 'o' && board[x][COUNT+1] == 'o' && board[x][COUNT+2] == 'o'){
    printf("Player One wins!\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  //same as above, but with player 2
  else if(board[x][COUNT] == 'x' && board[x][COUNT+1] == 'x' && board[x][COUNT+2] == 'x'){
    printf("Player Two wins!\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  ++x;
  if(x > 3)
  return;
  rowCheck();
  }

void columnCheck(){ //checks columns, repeats going across the columns
  //printf("x: %d\n",x); //for debugging
  //column check
  if(board[COUNT][x] == 'o' && board[COUNT+1][x] == 'o' && board[COUNT+2][x] == 'o'){
    printf("Player One wins!\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  else if(board[COUNT][x] == 'x' && board[COUNT+1][x] == 'x' && board[COUNT+2][x] == 'x'){
    printf("Player Two wins!\n");
    exit(1);
  } 
  ++x;
  if(x > 3)
  return;
  columnCheck();
  }

void diagonalCheck(){
  if(board[0][0] == 'o' && board[1][1] == 'o' && board[2][2] == 'o'){
    printf("Player One wins!\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  else if(board[0][2] == 'o' && board[1][1] == 'o' && board[2][0] == 'o'){
    printf("Player One wins!\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  if(board[0][0] == 'x' && board[1][1] == 'x' && board[2][2] == 'x'){
    printf("Player Two wins!\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  else if(board[0][2] == 'x' && board[1][1] == 'x' && board[2][0] == 'x'){
    printf("Player Two wins!\n");
    exit(1);
  }

}




/*ticTacToe.h*/
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define HEADER_H
#define BUFFER 256
#define COUNT 0

//prototypes
void boardSet();
void playGame();
void display();
void playerOne();
void playerTwo();
void checkWin(); 
void rowCheck();
void columnCheck();
void diagonalCheck();

//global variables
int board[3][3]; //column then row
int n;
int row[2];
int column[2];
```

You'll see in tic-tac-toe.c that I have a checkWin function, which itself calls rowCheck, columnCheck and diagonalCheck, with the added ability to call a draw. The problem is, my teacher wants the row, column and diagonal checks to be recursive, not hard-coded values. I thought I had done that to a degree, but it wasn't enough. I'm drawing a blank.

Comment: do not post links to the code.  Rather, copy and paste the code into your question (indent all the code an extra 4 spaces so stackoverflow with properly display your code)

Comment: I think you are mixing two things: recursive functions and 'magic numbers' (= hard coded values) instead of symbolic identifiers. I see no sense for recursive check functions.
Recursive function calls may become intersting when you want to search for possible draws which lead to an advantage of a computer player.
Please change the players' input which directly references to the board array!!! => Very dangerous!!!
Also move the variable definitions from the header file to the C file. In general, please do not allocate memory in header files.

Comment: I removed the link and pasted the entire program itself into the OP. Why should I move the variables from the header to C file?

Comment: You will have a lot of trouble if you include the header file in different C files!

Comment: @DFT95 header files are for declarations not definitions. Also using global variables is not good practice in general. (At least not when you do not need them)

Comment: Okay got it. I'll start kicking that habit. But back to the main question

Comment: Another improvement: 
Split the function void diagonalCheck() in two calls of a simpler function void diagonalCheck(char mark) which only checks for one of the players mark ('o' or 'x'). You avoid code clones with this.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean.
Do you want the algorithm to be recursice or repeating?

Comment: when writing header files, always include a 'include guard' so the file will not be included more than once.  It is also a good programming practice to not include header files those contents are not used in the CURRENT .c file

Comment: Your playGame function is already resursive!
An resursive call is here absolutely bad style. Avoid the exit calls and let your function return meaningful values.
Then you can check in playGame with the help of a do-while-loop if somebody has won and if to go on or not.

Comment: The program has to be recursive. According to my professor, this means taking out the hard coded values as well as recursively calling the checkWin function's rowCheck, columnCheck and diagonalCheck

Comment: a `include guard`:  `#ifndef TIC_TAC_TOE_H   (new line) #define TIC_TAC_TOW_H`  and at the end of the header file: `#endif // TIC_TAC_TOE_H`

Comment: do not declare (I.E. an instance) a variable in a header file.  The result is the (at link time) the linker will output messages about multiple instances of the same variable names.  Rather, in the header file place a `extern` statement for the variable and place the actual variable instance in a single file, like just above the `main()` function

Comment: when writing a prototype for a function that does not take any parameters, include a `void` inside the parens of the prototype.  Otherwise, the compiler will produce code to allow the function to take any number/kind of parameters when it is called.  Not what you (normally) want.

Comment: regarding: `  ++x;
  if(x > 3)
  return;`  1) for readability, indent the body of a `if` (say 4 spaces) to the right of the `if` starting column.  2) this checks if the value of `x` is 4, however, in C indexing any array is from 0 to (number of elements in array -1) so the value of `3` is beyond the end of the array, resulting in undefined behavior

Answer (score 1):

To have a recursive checkWin function, pass a parameter to it which says which row or column to check. After your actual check code implement a break condition (is next column/row invalid). If break condition is not true, call the function itself for the next column/row.

Answer (score 0):

suggest something similar to the following:

```
#define MAX_COLUMN 3
#define WIN 1
#define NO_WIN 0

int rowCheck( int row, int player, int column )
{   
    if( column == MAX_COLUMN )
    {
        return WIN;
    }

    if( board[ row ][ column ] != player )
    {
        return NO_WIN;
    }

    return rowCheck( row, player, column+1 );
}
```

also, since nothing in the (non-main) file is needed in the main file, except a couple of prototypes:  suggest your header contain only the following:

```
#ifndef TIC_TAC_TOW_H
#define TIC_TAC_TOW_H

boardSet( void ); // sets the board up
playGame( void ); // starts the game

#endif // TIC_TAC_TOW_H
```

all other statements in the current  header file should be moved to the file: `TicTacToe.c`